# My bakes are not coming out as crystal clear as I would like

Tags: normals, normal-map

I made a welder robot, and some of the faces on it are coming out really odd on the normal map ( like lots of color where there is no height or geometry). especially near the welder nozzle part. It is also really pixalated and some faces are severely dis configured. Does anyone know how to fix these problems?
I already tried adjusting the ray distance and sampling rate as well.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: get a render with color grid texture to check the texture stretching.

Comment: Maybe if you really can't fix your issues you can paint good colors over bad colors

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I think it might just be bad retop though.